# Simple bash script giving me problems

Tags: macos, bash, terminal, formatting

I'm having difficulty getting this bash script to perform the formatting of an input.
It's pretty straight-forward, but when it executes the line that starts with 'newstring=', it doesn't perform the sed operation, it only prints my input (up until the first white-space) then prints my sed command directly after.  What am I doing wrong?

```
#! /bin/bash

##format paths/strings with spaces to escape the spaces with a forward-slash'\'
##then use 'open' to open finder at current-set directory (based on path)

oldstring="$1"
newstring="$oldstring | sed 's/ /\\ /g')"
cd $newstring
open .
```

Answer (score 5):

You should simply do:

```
cd "$1"
open .
```

This avoids running sub-processes and deals with various problems that the `sed` script doesn't (such as names containing `$` symbols, or other shell metacharacters).  Generally, if a variable (or positional parameter such as `$1`) is a file name that could contain spaces, use it surrounded by double quotes every time.

Comment: Wow. Thank you. The simple solutions are always the best.

Answer (score 4):

Try putting the command in backquotes like

```
newstring=`echo "$oldstring" | sed 's/ /\\ /g')`
```

Comment: But, much better to use `newstring=$(echo "$oldstring" | sed 's/ /\\ /g')`.

Comment: Also, in `bash` (but not other shells AFAIK), you could use: `newstring=$(sed 's/ /\\ /g' <<< "$oldstring")`.  The double quotes around `$oldstring` might not be necessary, but can do no harm.

Comment: And, remove dangling `)` at the end of the statement

Answer (score 1):

@Jonathan Leffler's is the correct solution, since adding escapes doesn't actually do what you want but double-quoting does.  However, I'll take this opportunity to point out that there's a better way to add escapes using bash's built-in substitution capability instead of `sed`:

```
newstring="${oldstring/ /\\ }"
```

So there you have it, a better way to implement the wrong solution.  Personally, I voted for Jonathan's.